# Showing that the exponential expression $e^x (x-1) + 1$ is positive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I'm looking at

$$ f(x) = e^x (x-1) + 1$$

I'm having the feeling (based on the application where I am using it), that $f(x)$ should be strictly positive for $x > 0$. Indeed, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex%20*(x-1)%20%2B%201) plots it as such, with a global minimum of ($f(0)x=0$).

However, I fail to show this. It is trivial for $x \geq 1$, but what for $x < 1$?

Comment: It seems trivial to show $x> 0 \implies f'(x) > 0$.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

$f'(x)=x \, e^x > 0$ for $x>0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 21):

Since 
$$
e^x\ge 1+x
$$
and thus also 
$$
e^{-x}\ge 1-x
$$
one gets
$$
f(x)=e^x·(e^{-x}-(1-x))\ge 0.
$$

Comment: +^I just love it when all you ever wanted to know about the exponential is the inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$

Answer (score 14):

For $x\in(0,1)$, the inequality $e^x (x-1)+1 > 0$ is equivalent to:
$$ e^x  < \frac{1}{1-x} \tag{1}$$
or to:
$$ 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots < 1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots \tag{2} $$
that is trivial.

Comment: If confused by the last step, Jack converts $e^x$ to its Taylor series and the $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ to its geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

$$f^{'}(x)=e^{x}x$$
the derivative is positive for $x>1$ and thus it is increasing. I think you are having doubts about $x<1$. So 
you have two answers.

1. range of (0,1) which is increasing, since the derivative is positive.
2. From$ (-\infty,0)$ which is decreasing since $ e^{x}x$ becomes negative.